# Selecting multiple tags with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select all editable form elements (`input[type=text]`, `input[type="radio"]`, `input[type="checkbox"]`, `select` and `textarea`) that are not *readonly* or *disabled* and have a name. Is it possible to do it with a single selector without repeating the readonly and disabled attributes for each type?

In other words, can I provide `[name]:not([disabled]):not([readonly])` as a global filter, instead of repeating for each input type?

I am particularly interested in a single selector because, I want to give it as selector filter to `$.live` / `$.on`. I cannot use `.not` or any such methods because elements could be added dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"], select, textarea')
     .is(':not([disabled]):not([readonly])');
```

I found out this nice solution which seems to work.

```
$('(input[type="text"], input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"], select, textarea):not([disabled]):not([readonly])')
```

Basicly it seems you can add `()` around the selects and then do a :not() condition. God I love jQuery!

Comment: I am looking for a single selector that satisfies all the conditions. Cannot use `.is`.

Comment: Ummm... I guess you just can do a `if ($(this).attr('disabled') || $(this).attr('readonly')) return false;` inside the live/on function?

Comment: That is my current solution. I was curious to know if there is another solution.

Comment: as far as i know there is no `:readonly` selector in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Thanks Robin. The second solution was what i was searching for. `(input,textarea)[name]:not([readonly]):enabled` worked. You shouldn't put space between `input,textarea`. http://jsfiddle.net/dQ88c/

Answer (score 1):

you can use `filter` method:

```
$("input[type='text']:enabled, textarea:enabled, select:enabled, input[type='radio']:enabled")
.filter(function(){ return $(this).attr("readonly", false); // or true
}).on("click", function(){
     .....
})
```

Comment: Can't use `.not` because these are for `.live` binding. Elements will be added dynamically.

Comment: @Joyce Babu you can use `:enabled` selector.